# Ruby: Capybara: How to fill text field with some text without clearing previously entered text in the field

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, capybara

I need to add some text into the text field that already contains text.
When I use fill_in or set functions - it clears previously entered text. 
So how to add text into text box without clearing previously entered data in it?

Comment: What driver are you using with Capybara? Some drivers have different options for this (selenium driver specifically).

Comment: I use Selenium driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Selenium you can do

```
fill_in('whatever', with: 'text to append', fill_options: {clear: :none})
```

or

```
field.set('whatever', clear: :none)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
field = find_field 'Text field'
field.set("#{field.value} and something more...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Capybara::Node::Element#send_keys`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FElement%3Asend_keys) on your field in question to append more text to it.  For example:

```
find('#your-text-field').send_keys("this is more text to add")
```